# Ruby On Rails "undefined method `description' for #" when save

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, save

I'm relatively new to rails and I've been struggling with this for a couple of days. I'd be much appreciated if you can see where I've gone wrong.

I got this error message

```
 undefined method `description' for #<Invoicegeneric:0x000001054900b0>

 if @invoicegeneric.save   ==> error at this
    response = "Success"
  else
    response = "Error"
```

and this is my controller code

```
def addgenericitems

  @invoicegeneric = Invoicegeneric.new
  @invoicegeneric.invoice_id = params[:invoice_id]
  @invoicegeneric.po_id = params[:po_id]

  if @invoicegeneric.save
    response = "Success"
  else
    response = "Error"
  end

render :json => {:html => render_to_string(:partial => "invoices/invoicegenerics", :layout => false) }.to_json, :status => :ok
end
```

and this is my html

```
  <form id="modal-form" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" 
        name="invoicegenericform" action="<%= addgenericitems_invoice_path(@invoice) %>" 
  method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="po_id">PO</label>
            <select name="po_id" class="chzn-select">
            <% Purchaseorder.active.order(:sku).each do |p| %>
              <option value="<%= p.sku %>"><%= "#{p.sku}" %></option>
            <% end %>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="sku_sj">SJ</label>
            <input name="sku_sj" type="text">
        </fieldset>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="pure-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>

        <input type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" value="Tambah"/>

    </div>
</form>
```

In my table there is no column name description

Comment: Can we see the `Invoicegeneric` model? Also, it's good practice to camel case that model. `InvoiceGeneric` in `app/models/invoice_generic.rb`.

Comment: yeah I found it, the problem is in my Invoicegeneric model. I give validate for :description. I remove that validate. And it works. Thanks @Deefour